# How to download and store image in device while upgrading database in android application?

Tags: android, jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

Is there any way to download image from internet and store it in SD Card / Phone Memory and use it for future while upgrading database in Android application? I'm using HTML5 / Phonegap / jQuery Mobile.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Lazy Loaders", [Here](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList) you will find fedorvlasov's lazy image loader. It also has file cache and memory cache, so you can store the images you downloaded and use later on when your device is not connected to the internet.

Comment: can this be used for html5 / phonegap / jquery - mobile ?

Comment: It depends on what kind of application you will create with phonegap. As far as I know, since you can also use the Native side efficiently with plugins in phonegap, I think you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here

http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-download-fileimage-url-your-device

And then you can save path file inside an DB by SQLite. Look for SQLite Android tutorial

Comment: can this be used for html5 / phonegap / jquery - mobile ?